# PHP - Public method; can't fetch return values on mysql query

Tags: php, oop, pdo

First all i'm new on OOP. I have a function that is calling all values from my `product_photos` table. Somehow i cant reach return values on table column names. It's always returning null.
My Method:

```
public function getProductPhotosWebService() {
    $this->prepare('SELECT * FROM product_photos');
    $this->execute();
    $this->param = $this->fetchAll();
    return $this->param;
}
```

in my view i use method;

```
$productPhotos  = $products->getProductPhotosWebService();
```

when i `var_dump($productPhotos)` result it returns values;

```
array (size=388)
  0 => 
    object(stdClass)[9]
      public 'product_photo_id' => string '1' (length=1)
      public 'product_photo_name' => string 'B' (length=1)
      public 'product_id' => string '1' (length=1)
      public 'order_id' => string '1' (length=1)
      public 'add_date' => string '2015-05-11 21:59:22' (length=19)
      public 'add_user' => string '1' (length=1)
      public 'upd_date' => string '2015-10-13 16:03:32' (length=19)
      public 'upd_user' => string '1' (length=1)
      public 'visibility' => string '1' (length=1)
  1 => 
    object(stdClass)[10]
      public 'product_photo_id' => string '2' (length=1)
      public 'product_photo_name' => string 'B' (length=1)
      public 'product_id' => string '1' (length=1)
      public 'order_id' => string '2' (length=1)
      public 'add_date' => string '2015-05-11 21:59:35' (length=19)
      public 'add_user' => string '1' (length=1)
      public 'upd_date' => string '2015-05-11 21:59:35' (length=19)
      public 'upd_user' => string '1' (length=1)
      public 'visibility' => string '1' (length=1)
  2 => 
    object(stdClass)[11]
      public 'product_photo_id' => string '3' (length=1)
      public 'product_photo_name' => string 'B' (length=1)
      public 'product_id' => string '2' (length=1)
      public 'order_id' => string '3' (length=1)
      public 'add_date' => string '2015-05-13 12:29:50' (length=19)
      public 'add_user' => string '2' (length=1)
      public 'upd_date' => string '2015-10-13 16:03:34' (length=19)
      public 'upd_user' => string '1' (length=1)
      public 'visibility' => string '1' (length=1)
```

But i can't use `$productPhotos->product_id` it returns `NULL`.

What am i missing?
Any help greatly appricated.

**PS: I'm not using any Framework.**

Comment: `$this` has special meaning in OOP.

Comment: *"`$this` is a protected variable that's used within a object, `$this` allows you to access a class file internally."*

Comment: you have been given an answer now; ask them.

Comment: @Fred-ii- actullay my method is a class's method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$productPhotos` is an array.

```
foreach ($productPhotos as $productPhoto) {
    echo $productPhoto->product_id, "\n";
}
```